# timeago.js timeago function inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timeago

I have this time element that is created dynamically.

```html
<time class="timeago" datetime="/*Current Time*/"></time>
```

So i have been using this script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.timeago').timeago();
});
```

As the element is created dynamically, the document.ready function doesnt seem to work on it. My question is, is there anyway to add the timeago function inline like this:

```html
<time class="timeago" datetime="/*Current Time*/" onload="timeago();"></time>
```

or a document.ready function for dynamically created elements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're adding the element dynamically?

Comment: If you have access to the dom node of the element when you are adding it into the DOM, you can directly call `node.timeago()` also.

Comment: $('.div').append('<time class="timeago" datetime="/*Current Time*/"></time>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding the element dynamically you need to trigger `timeago()` once the element is added.

Change your script to

```
$('.div').append('<time class="timeago" datetime="/*Current Time*/"></time>');
$(".div .timeago").timeago();
```

Comment: Welcome. Can you please accept the answer? @RidanMuhammedAsif